# Python library kivy - popup textinput

Tags: python, kivy, popup, inputtext

Hello everyone I am writing a small program for sorting goods, the program is already ready in the console version, but I would like to implement it in a graphical version. The essence of the problem: I'm sitting at what time and thinking how to implement pop-up windows with text input for this part of the code. I will be grateful for your help.
here is the code:

> ```
> def add_product(self, instance):
>     code = input("Введите код товара: ")
>     category_code = input("Введите код категории товара: ")
>     name = input("Введите наименование товара: ")
>     description = input("Введите описание товара: ")
>     price = float(input("Введите цену товара: "))
>     quantity = int(input("Введите количество товара: "))
>     popup = Popup(title='Добавить товар', content=content, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
>     popup.open()
>     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO products VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
>                    (code, category_code, name, description, price, quantity))
>     conn.commit()
>     
> # Удаление товара
> def delete_product(self, instance):
>     code = input("Введите код товара для удаления: ")
>     popup = Popup(title='Удалить товар', content=content, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
>     popup.open()
>     cursor.execute("DELETE FROM products WHERE code=?", (code,))
>     conn.commit()
>
> # Корректировка товара
> def edit_product(self, instance):
>     code = input("Введите код товара для корректировки: ")
>     cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM products WHERE code=?", (code,))
>     product = cursor.fetchone()
>     if product is not None:
>         print("Текущая информация о товаре:")
>         print(product)
>     popup = Popup(title='Изменить товар', content=content, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
>     popup.open()
>     # Ввод новых значений для товара
>     new_code = input("Введите новый код товара: ")
>     popup = Popup(title='Введите новый код товара:', content=content, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
>     popup.open()
>     new_category_code = input("Введите новый код категории товара: ")
>     new_name = input("Введите новое наименование товара: ")
>     new_description = input("Введите новое описание товара: ")
>     new_price = float(input("Введите новую цену товара: "))
>     new_quantity = int(input("Введите новое количество товара: "))
>
>     # Обновление записи в базе данных
>     cursor.execute("UPDATE products SET code=?, category_code=?, name=?, description=?, price=?, quantity=? WHERE code=?",
>                    (new_code, new_category_code, new_name, new_description, new_price, new_quantity, code))
>     conn.commit()
>
>     print("Информация о товаре успешно обновлена.")
>
> # Поиск товара по наименованию и модели
> def search_product(self, instance):
>     search_term = input("Введите наименование или модель товара для поиска: ")
>
>     cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?",
>                    (f"%{search_term}%", f"%{search_term}%"))
>     products = cursor.fetchall()
>     if products:
>         print("Результаты поиска:")
>         for product in products:
>             print(product)
>     else:
>         print("Товар не найден.")
> # Сортировка товаров по коду, цене и имени
> def sort_products(self, instance):
>     sort_option = input("Выберите опцию сортировки (code, price, name): ")
>     cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY {sort_option}")
>     products = cursor.fetchall()
>     if products:
>         print("Отсортированный список товаров:")
>         for product in products:
>             print(product)
>     else:
>         print("Список товаров пуст.")
> ```

Here's what I tried:

```
 def show_add_product(self, instance):
        content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        code_input = TextInput(hint_text='Код товара')
        content.add_widget(code_input)
        category_code_input = TextInput(hint_text='Код категории товара')
        content.add_widget(category_code_input)
        name_input = TextInput(hint_text='Наименование товара')
        content.add_widget(name_input)
        description_input = TextInput(hint_text='Описание товара')
        content.add_widget(description_input)
        price_input = TextInput(hint_text='Цена товара')
        content.add_widget(price_input)
        quantity_input = TextInput(hint_text='Количество товара')
        content.add_widget(quantity_input)
        add_button = Button(text='Добавить', size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 50))
        content.add_widget(add_button)

        def add_product(instance):
            code = code_input.text
            category_code = category_code_input.text
            name = name_input.text
            description = description_input.text
            price = float(price_input.text)
            quantity = int(quantity_input.text)

            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO products VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                           (code, category_code, name, description, price, quantity))
            conn.commit()

            popup.dismiss()

        add_button.bind(on_press=add_product)

        popup = Popup(title='Добавить товар', content=content, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        popup.open()
```

But the add button does not respond

Comment: Please refactor your question to a more specific question which only contains code which is relevant to that question. Someone trying to answer is ideally capable of copying and pasting your code into their editor and work on your problem.